# how to set flutter app full screen forever?

Tags: flutter

`SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky, overlays: []);`
when i use the above code in root widget, app is full screen.
but when a `TextFiled` widget is focused, the status bar and nav bar will show again, and never hide.

maybe i can run the code `SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.immersiveSticky, overlays: []);` again when the `TextField` unfocused, but i do not want to do that.

is there any elegant solution?

Comment: Hi there, welcome to StackOverflow. Can you please provide the relevant code where you are having difficulty or issue ?

Answer (score 0):

You can Manually reset to the previous fullscreen mode when user clicks a button or outside.

```
        ElevatedButton(
        onPressed: () {
          Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 1)).then((_) {
            SystemChrome.restoreSystemUIOverlays();
          });
          FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
        },
        child: const Text("Hide Overlay")),
```

Please refer the Flutter API documentation here. They have mentioned the issue and provided 2 solutions. [Flutter>services>SystemChrome>setEnabledSystemUIMode](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/SystemChrome/setEnabledSystemUIMode.html)

Comment: Is there any other way to rollback the prev status?

Comment: i am using `WidgetsBindingObserver` to listen if the keyboard is disappeared.